# jQuery UI draggable prevent duplicates

Tags: jquery-ui, duplicates, draggable

I have a list of items on the left that can be dragged into any of the boxes on the right.  The items can be in many boxes but should only occur once per box.  I am trying to get hold of the ids of the draggable item and compare that against the id's of all the items already in the box, but can't seem to get it right.  My code is as follows:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: ".draggable"
});
$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "true",
    placeholder: ".droppable-placeholder",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        //console.dir(ui.helper[0]);

        var listContainer = ui.helper[0].closest('ul');
        if (listContainer) {
        
          console.dir(listContainer);
          listContainer.find('li').each(function() { //This is not right
              var sortableItemId = $(this).attr("id");
              console.dir($(this));
              console.log("sortable item id " + sortableItemId);
          });
        }
    }
});


$("ul, li").disableSelection();
$(".draggable-column, .droppable-column").on("click", ".close-list-item", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    float: left;
}

li {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.draggable-column {
    height: 100%;
}

.droppable-item {
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    align-content: space-between;
}

.droppable-item > h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable {
    width: 230px;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.droppable-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    /* equal height of the children*/
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
    /* additionally, equal width */
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 draggable-column">
        <ul class="" id="draggable-column-list">
            <li class="draggable " id="item1">1 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item2">2 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item3">3 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item4">4 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item5">5 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 droppable-column">

        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 1
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item1">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3 class="">
              Item 2
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item2">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 3
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item3">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 4
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item4">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 5
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item5">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 6
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item6">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am basically trying to stop duplicates occurring in the same box.

Comment: So how are you currently comparing the item dropped to the items in the list already?

Comment: @Twisty, sorry I was in tiswas and had removed a lot of the code that just wasn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally worked out a possible solution although it is not particularly clean:

```js
$(".sortable").sortable({
    revert: true,
    connectWith: ".draggable"
   
});

$(".draggable").draggable({
    connectToSortable: ".sortable",
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "true",
    placeholder: ".droppable-placeholder",
    
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        console.log("--start of stop");
        var listContainer = $(ui.helper[0].parentElement);
        var newListId = listContainer.attr("id");
        var draggableId = $(this).attr("id");
        var cloneId = newListId + "-" + draggableId;
        console.log("new list id: " + newListId);
        console.log("draggableId: " + draggableId);
        console.log("cloneId: " + cloneId);
        var itemExists = false;
        $("#"+ newListId).find('li').each(function() {
            var sortableItemId = $(this).attr("id");
            console.log("sortable item id " + sortableItemId);
            if (sortableItemId != undefined && sortableItemId == cloneId) {
             console.log("***  sortable item already exists");
             itemExists = true;
            } 
        });
        if (itemExists) {
         $("#" + cloneId).remove();
        }
        $(ui.helper[0]).attr("id", cloneId);
        
        console.log("--end of stop");

    },

});


$("ul, li").disableSelection();
$(".draggable-column, .droppable-column").on("click", ".close-list-item", function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.7em;
    float: left;
}

li {
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 0.5em;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.draggable-column {
    height: 100%;
}

.droppable-item {
    padding: 0.5em;
    float: left;
    align-content: space-between;
}

.droppable-item > h3 {
    text-align: center;
}

.sortable {
    width: 230px;
    height: 10em;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

.droppable-placeholder {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    /* equal height of the children*/
}

.col {
    flex: 1;
    /* additionally, equal width */
    padding: 1em;
    border: solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 draggable-column">
        <ul class="" id="draggable-column-list">
            <li class="draggable " id="item1">1 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item2">2 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item3">3 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item4">4 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="draggable " id="item5">5 Drag me onto item
                <a href="#" class="close-list-item">
                    <i class="fa fa-window-close"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-8 droppable-column">

        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 1
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item1">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3 class="">
              Item 2
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item2">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 3
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item3">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 4
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item4">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 5
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item5">

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="droppable-item">
            <h3>
              Item 6
            </h3>
            <ul class="sortable" id="ul-item6">

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this as well  and could not make it work with the control's default functionality. I implemented a solution similar to the answer but in the 'Receive' handler. Basically after the item was added I look for duplicates and then just remove the current added duplicate. This also does not look very clean but works. I really think the sortable  control should have this functionality and if it does, it is not well documented. I guess if you really want to add a proper solution, you would need to write an extension that hooks into the mousedrop event and try and prevent adding before the receive handler fires...

Note: I use a sortable list as the drop target and a list with draggable items as the source.

Here is my solution:

```
$(".sortable").sortable({
revert: "invalid",
connectWith: ".draggable",
placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
forcePlaceholderSize: true,
receive: function (event, ui) {
    var addedItem = $($(this).data().uiSortable.currentItem);
    addedItem.prop("id", "dropped_" + $(ui.item[0]).prop("id"));

    // Elaborate way to check duplicates and remove them when added. Could not find a way to prevent the item from being dropped
    var childItems = $(this).children("li");
    var idCount = {};

    $.each(childItems, function (i, node) {
        var currentId = $(node).prop("id");
        if (idCount[currentId] != undefined) {
            if (addedItem.prop("id") === currentId) {
                addedItem.remove();
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            idCount[currentId] = true;
        }
    });
}
});
```

The draggable object as follows:

```
 $(".draggable").draggable({
     connectToSortable: ".sortable-droptarget",
     helper: "clone",
     revert: "invalid"
 });
```